# Command + C does not always work from the first try in Microsoft Word (Office 2011)

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

I have no idea why <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't always register from the first time. I sometimes try to copy something off Word, but I have to press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> more than once for it to register, otherwise <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> just prints what was copied in clipboard before. This becomes very irritating.

However I realised that if I press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> then pause for a second, THEN press <kbd>C</kbd>, the command always registers.

***EDIT***

I noticed that when I select any text in word, it takes about a second for the Cut and Copy buttons to be highlighted (otherwise they're greyed out). And THIS has direct effect on this problem. Only when they are not greyed out anymore can I copy and paste using keyboard shortcuts correctly.

What is happening ?

Comment: Do you have any accessibility options turned on in system preferences? That can effect the key combos.

Comment: Do you have PopClip or similar installed?

Comment: I have the same problem and I've not found a solution for it. My 2011 MacBook Pro was serviced for a new battery and I had them do their hardware test on my keyboard and it showed nothing. I thought maybe a crumb was in there or something because for me, my right command key works perfectly and the left is sporadic like yours. Because my left command key gets the most use I thought maybe it was the angle I was hitting it with my thumb but alas, no matter how I hit it when it's failing it's failing.

Comment: If you have the same problem with other key combinations like Command+W, Command+V, etc your Command key is showing signs of wear and tear. You probably can improve the keyboard responsiveness by cleaning/lubricating the contacts of the affected Command key to improve conductivity (I know that will be difficult in a MacBook Pro, but I can't think of another solution, except replacing the keyboard). See http://www.jagshouse.com/fixingkeyboards.html and http://superuser.com/questions/313488/whats-the-best-lubricant-to-use-on-mechanical-keyboards for more information.

Comment: @jaume I really doubt its wear and tear, the laptop is less than a year old.

Comment: According to the question this only occurs with Word. Unfortunately Word for Mac is not running optimally on several fronts, so this might just be one of those quirks it has.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate Bart ?? Yes it only happens with words, I usually use the font Cambria.

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought it might be a hardware issue also but I have now switched to a new MBP retina a couple of months ago and it is still the same. I am using Word from Office 2008 though, and I am wondering if it is a problem limited to that version, or if maybe it also doesn't work in Office 2012. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: have the same issue but dont really have a solution :( Its not wear and tear because its a new computer!

Comment: It seems that pressing the command button takes a while to process and change from menu bar to formatting bar etc .. its a MAC OS issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Mac OS problem. I just copied perfectly in Chrome, but I face the same problem as everyone is facing in Word.

Comment: Fix it! I deleted all of Word's prefs files etc etc and then suddenly Microsoft AutoUpdate found a whole bunch of updates that it previously didn't know about. Now everything works fine again.

Answer (score -2):

This issue is real and I think every mac user experience it on a weekly basis, but likely people continue to doubt themselves over if they actually command c or not properly.

**The fix.** If you are using Karabiner like real hacker should:

Just add this to your karabiner complex configurations:

```
[
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "c",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    }
]
```

Now that should make the copy flash a few times in the menu.

You can increase or decrease as much as you want. Personally I have a few more.